# How can I query django models using modulo?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, datetime-format, python-datetime

I want to send an email to users who haven't activated their accounts every 120 days. I'm using a `DateTimeField` for their `created` attribute.

How can I retrieve a queryset of users for whom `created % 120 == 0`?

Here's what I'm trying, using `annotate` and `F` objects:

```
members = Member.objects.annotate(
    days_old=(datetime.datetime.now() - F('created'))
)
members = members.annotate(modulo_days=F('days_old') % 120)
members = members.filter(modulo_days=0)
```

...but this returns the errors:

> TypeError: expected string or buffer
>
> ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: interval % integer

How can I retrieve this queryset looking for the modulo of a timestamp on a Django model?

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing a queryset that could work for you:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime

to_compare_datetime = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=180)
members = Member.objects.filter(account_activated=False, created__year=to_compare_datetime.year, created__month=to_compare_datetime.month, created__day=to_compare_datetime.day)
```

I'm supposing that your `Member` model has a field `account_activated`, and that the `created` field is a `DateTimeField`. Hope this can help you :)